# APISIX gateway setup

Tags: docker, api-gateway, apache-apisix

I am trying to create a APISIX gateway for my microservice. I have used the docker to install APISIX gateway using the apisix documentation Getting started (https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/getting-started/README/) Version 3.3.0. It works for route:

```
curl -i "http://127.0.0.1:9180/apisix/admin/routes" -X PUT -d '
{
  "id": "getting-started-ip",
  "uri": "/ip",
  "upstream": {
    "type": "roundrobin",
    "nodes": {
      "httpbin.org:80": 1
    }
  }
}'
```

and `curl "http://127.0.0.1:9080/ip"` it returns the expected response.

Now i want to change the upstream to localhost:XXXX. I have my dummy api server running at localhost:XXXX (not on docker)

if i do `curl "http://localhost:XXXX/api/v1/test_server/testing"` it returns back `{ success: true}`  as json

now i want to change the apisix upstream as the dummy api server i.e. localhost:XXXX,
so what did was change the upstream:

```
curl -i "http://127.0.0.1:9180/apisix/admin/routes" -X PUT -d '
{
  "id": "1",
  "uri": "/api/v1/test_server/testing",
  "upstream": {
    "type": "roundrobin",
    "nodes": {
      "localhost:XXXX": 1
    }
  }
}'
```

but when i try to do `curl "http://127.0.0.1:9080/api/v1/test_server/testing"` it shows

```
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty</center>
<p><em>Powered by <a href="https://apisix.apache.org/">APISIX</a>.</em></p></body>
</html>
```

and in the docker log of APISIX it shows

```
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: localhost, server: _, request: "GET /api/v1/test_server/testing HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://localhost:XXXX/api/v1/test_server/testing", host: "<host ip and port>"
```

Can you help me why it not able to stablish connection to my local server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the gateway running in a container, but the backend outside a container?  [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) discusses this situation in detail.

Comment: Yes, the APISIX gateway is running in docker container but my backend server is running outside the container. is there a way or i have to run my backend server inside the container also. @DavidMaze

Comment: configuring nginx, you can troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue, this might be network issue related to docker networking
try to dockerize your dummy api server and run it in the same network of apisix configured in the docker-compose file

as 502 is usually because you can’t access your upstream service through apisix. In docker, if you want to access your host service, you can change the upstream hostname from localhost to `host.docker.internal` if you are using macOS, or 172.17.0.1 if you are using Linux  And try to see if you can access it through APISIX

Comment: replacing localhost with `host.docker.internal` while creating route worked for me

Answer (score 2):

1. You deploy APISIX inside a Docker container.
2. You have one service running outside of the Docker container.
3. You can't use "localhost:xxxx" inside Docker container, because APISIX will try to access the localhost inside the Docker container instead of your host.

This question is related to your Docker knowledge, check [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)